Google Sign-In "Permission denied to generate login hint for target domain" Error in Flask
Question:
I am trying to implement Google Sign-In in my Flask application, but I keep encountering the following error: "Permission denied to generate login hint for target domain." I have checked my credentials, authorized redirect URIs, and OAuth Consent Screen settings, but I can't seem to figure out what's causing the problem.
Here's the relevant part of my code:
# Google Sign-in Configuration
os.environ["OAUTHLIB_INSECURE_TRANSPORT"] = "1"
GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID = "YOUR_CLIENT_ID_HERE"
flow = Flow.from_client_secrets_file(
    client_secrets_file="static/client_secret.json",
    scopes=["openid", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile"],
    redirect_uri="http://127.0.0.1:5000/callback"
)

# Google login route
@app.route("/login_google")
def login_google():
    authorization_url, state = flow.authorization_url(prompt='consent')
    session["state"] = state
    return redirect(authorization_url)

# Google callback route
@app.route("/callback")
def callback():
    flow.fetch_token(authorization_response=request.url)
    if not session["state"] == request.args["state"]:
        abort(500)  # State does not match!

    credentials = flow.credentials
    request_session = requests.session()
    cached_session = cachecontrol.CacheControl(request_session)
    token_request = google.auth.transport.requests.Request(session=cached_session)

    id_info = id_token.verify_oauth2_token(
        id_token=credentials._id_token,
        request=token_request,
        audience=GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID
    )

    session["google_id"] = id_info.get("sub")
    session["name"] = id_info.get("name")
    return redirect("/protected_area")

# Protected area route
@app.route("/protected_area")
@login_is_required
def protected_area():
    return f"Hello {session['name']}! <br/> <a href='/logout'><button>Logout</button></a>"

# Logout route
@app.route("/logout")
def logout():
    session.clear()
    return redirect("/")

I have ensured that:
My Google API credentials are correctly set up.
The authorized redirect URIs in the Google Cloud Console match my redirect URI in the code.
I have included all necessary scopes in the OAuth Consent Screen.
Despite these checks, I'm still encountering the error. Could someone please help me identify what might be causing this issue?
Thank you!
I have ensured that:
My Google API credentials are correctly set up.
The authorized redirect URIs in the Google Cloud Console match my redirect URI in the code.
I have included all necessary scopes in the OAuth Consent Screen.
Despite these checks, I'm still encountering the error. Could someone please help me identify what might be causing this issue?
Thank you!
